# FreeBusy not work for on Time 00:00 in my jquery week calendar plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-week-calendar

I have used `Jquery-weekcalendar plugin` .

In that i am using `freebusy` for prevent some part from creating event on that time .
Its work fine for all Time Except `00:00`

My Problem :

I have `freebusy` with

```
 freebusys: [{"start":"2013-08-10T00:00:00", "end":"2013-08-10T23:00:00", "free": false},
```

So block time `From 00:00 to 23:00 on 10th august`

1>When i am try to create event on `00:15 TO 00:45` than its prevent Its Fine.

You can see :

[image]

2>
  But on same way i am try to create event `00:00 TO 00:15` But its allow me to create event  is `unexpected` output`for me.  (`expected` : not allow to create)

You can see here :

[image]

Comment: `@ankit337` so what you want from our side...?

Comment: `@win` I want In second case ( 12:00 AM TO 12:15 AM ) prevent me from creating event Because its also in block area . But right now is not happening.

Comment: @Vijay Please look in to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30640972/login-popup-model-with-spring-mvc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### As i not found any legal way to solve this So i have solve this problem like this

**Problem** is when we click on "`2013-08-10T00:00:00`" than `freebusy manager` is going to find in `"2013-07-10T00:00:00" to "2013-08-10T24:00:00"` so its find this block `is not busy` and `allow to create new event` .

**Solution:**
I have solve this by replacing my click event time(00:00:00) To (00:00:01) only in this case, So its work for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue I think also. If I remember correctly you have to check manually if the new event overlaps with the freebusy times. I think since the start times are the same it's still evaluating as "free". Try checking also that the end time of your new event also does not fall inside a freeBusy.

Comment: problem is when we click on `"2013-08-10T00:00:00"` than `freebusy manager` is going to find in `"2013-07-10T00:00:00" to "2013-08-10T24:00:00"` so its find this block is not `busy` and allow to create new event . I have solve this by replacing my click event time(`00:00:00`) To (`00:00:01`) so its work for me